# Insert and select data from MySQL in WordPress Page

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am designing a WordPress website, I am thorough with the design part, Now the next phase is the database related things.

```
1. Insert data into database.
2. Select the data and display it in the page.
3. Where i need to create a php page if i dont want to install widget.? where i need the place the code?
```

I have googled some plugin and I got `php code widget` plugin and inserted into one of my pages as a widget

I tried installing insert_php plugin but its not working so I am continuing with php_code_widget

`Pages-> All Pages-> Home Page -> Add Row -> Add Widget -> Php Code Widget.`

Now in my MySQL Database I have a simple table called Rituals having three columns

```
 Ritual ID-> Int -> Auto Increament.
 Ritual_Name-> varchar
 Ritual_Active-> varchar.
```

Now I need to insert the Ritual name to the database,
And with some reference I got this code and I have put it in the php code widget window.

```
<?php
 require_once('../../../wp-load.php');
 function insertuser(){

 if(isset($_POST['submit']){
 global $wpdb;
 $rname=$_POST['rname'];
 $ractive=$_POST['ractive'];
 $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "mahathiwp";
  $wpdb->insert($table_name, array ('Ritual_Name' => $rname, 'Ritual_Active' =>   $ractive) ); 
 }
 ?>
  <form action="" method="post">
  Ritual Name: <input type="text" name="rname" /><br><br>
  Ritual Active: <input type="text" name="ractive" /><br><br> 
 <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
 </form>

 <?php

 }

insertuser();
?>
```

`Data is not getting inserted.`

Can you suggest the proper and faster way to insert the data into the database and also to retrieve the data and show it in my WordPress page. Any help appreciated.

Comment: ```if(){``` If what?

Comment: ` if(){` it should be ` if(isset($_POST['submit'])){`

Comment: now i have added it, Thank u

Comment: To fix the Fatal error, try ```require_once(dirname( __FILE__ ).'/../../../wp-load.php');```

Comment: Are you getting any other errors?

Comment: No errors. data is not getting inserted to database

Comment: put ```$wpdb->show_errors();``` before the insert and/or ```$wpdb->print_error();``` at the end and see what it shows.

Comment: This error am getting `Call to a member function show_errors() on a non-object`

Comment: okay,Let me check

Comment: data is not inserted because you are doing wrong way

Comment: are you aware about page template??

Comment: @VasimVanzara Please suggest the right way. Should i need to create a template? If so then where i need to place it. How i am able to call it in wordpress page?

Comment: are making plugin or creating a page??

Comment: I am creating a page where i have a simple form , form elements should be inserted to database and the i need to retrieve back and show the details to the user

Comment: it on front end??

Comment: Can you give your email id so that i can give the detailed description of my problem?

Comment: Right, so this has moved off-site now? Why not give the detailed description of your problem here in the first place, that is what this is for isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to customize your theme,

Add code to make an action while form is submitted.

**functions.php**

```
function childtheme_style_andscripts(){
    //wp_enqueue_style('parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_script('ajax-function',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/ajaxfunction.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true );
    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-function', 'usersubmitform', array(
        'url'=> admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
        'security'=> wp_create_nonce('our-nonce')
    ) );
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','childtheme_style_andscripts');


function form_action_function(){
    require_once(dirname( __FILE__ ).'/../../../wp-load.php');
    $data = $_POST['data'];
    global $wpdb;
    if( !check_ajax_referer('our-nonce', 'security' ) ){

        wp_send_json_error('security failed');

        return;

    }
    //var_dump($data);
    $rname=$data['rname'];
    $ractive=$data['ractive'];

    $table_name = "rituals";
    $wpdb->insert($table_name, array ('rname' => $rname, 'ractive' => $ractive) ); 

    $wpdb->show_errors();
    $wpdb->print_error();
    echo 'From Submitted Successfully';

    die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_form_action_function','form_action_function');
add_action('wp_ajax_form_action_function','form_action_function');
```

**Custom Page Template**

```
<?php
/**
    Template Name: Form For User
 */

get_header(); ?>

<div id="main-content" class="main-content">

<?php
    if ( is_front_page() && twentyfourteen_has_featured_posts() ) {
        // Include the featured content template.
        get_template_part( 'featured-content' );
    }
?>
    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">
            <h1 class="headingform">User Form</h1>
            <div class="msg"></div>
            <form  class="userform">
                Ritual Name: <input type="text" id="rname" name="rname" /><br><br>
                Ritual Active: <input type="text" id="ractive" name="ractive" /><br><br> 
                <input  id="usersubmit"type="submit" Value="Submit" />
            </form>

        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->
    <?php get_sidebar( 'content' ); ?>
</div><!-- #main-content -->

<?php
get_sidebar();
get_footer();
```

**ajax-admin.js**

Here I have use ajax that why this file is created.put this file into you theme js folder.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    var submitButton = document.getElementById('usersubmit');

    var ajaxFunctionformprocess = function(fromdata, action){
        $.ajax({
            type:'post',
            url: usersubmitform.url,
            data:{
                action:action,
                data:fromdata,
                security:usersubmitform.security,



            },
            success:function(reponse){
                $('div.msg').html(reponse);
            },
            error:function(response){
                alert(response);
            }

        });



    }

    submitButton.addEventListener('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var fromdata = {
            'rname':document.getElementById('rname').value,
            'ractive':document.getElementById('ractive').value,
        };
        ajaxFunctionformprocess(fromdata, 'form_action_function');  

        });




});
```

Comment: you have to create page template in your theme

Comment: I have use a default theme you have to make as per your requirement.

Comment: The code works in a flash, How can i write the code the display the entered data in a list?